# Auto shrink a button without interaction

Tags: css

I'd like to add a menu button in the top right corner of my site - just a simple circle with an icon. I'd like to to load at a certain height and width and then automatically shrink, a few moments later, to another height and width - all without any user interaction.

Is this possible?

Any CSS gurus out there?

Many thanks,

Comment: What have you tried? This is definitely possible, just requires a tiny bit of JS. Look in to the js function `setTimeout`, as this will allow you to wait x seconds before running a function to update the size. As for updating the size, look in to adding and removing styles and/or css classes with javascript.

Comment: This can be done without JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the ***CSS3 Animation***:

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #00f;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-name: shrink; /* "calling" the animation */
  animation-duration: 1s; /* adjust */
  animation-timing-function: linear; /* specifies the speed curve of an animation / also try other values */
  animation-delay: 3s; /* adjust */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* retains in the state set by the last keyframe */
}

@keyframes shrink { /* let's call it "shrink" */
  0%   {width: 50px; height: 50px}
  100% {width: 25px; height: 25px} /* final state */
}
```

```html
<div><div>
```

Experiment and adjust to your needs.

*Note*: There are also other *animation* properties & values so you might take a closer look to see what you can do.

Comment: Terrific. Thank you very much.